# PHP post variable isn't returning the whole string value of the hidden input field after submission?

Tags: php, html, input, php-5.3, php-5.4

I have this input field that is hidden named `loginfo` containing this value, after submission, I only get half of the value, and I set the `maxlength` to 20000

```
<input type="hidden" name="loginfo" value='<?=  $user_log_info ?>' maxlength="2000" />

Cookie Info: a:20:{s:11:"NO_TRACKING";s:4:"true";s:9:"PHPSESSID";s:26:"pvbmhif06sd25584sl75tl7qs3";s:13:"orig_referrer";s:29:"http://dev-sti.planetart.com/";s:5:"email";s:23:"semirindi@planetart.com";s:12:"cookie_check";s:4:"done";s:15:"recently_viewed";s:5:"23795";s:15:"user_last_paper";s:2:"CS";s:24:"user_last_size_RECTANGLE";s:3:"5x7";s:18:"user_last_quantity";s:2:"25";s:7:"cart_id";s:32:"64a0d1346aff6ff6aeb7f6a78c9ad156";s:23:"shopping_cart_tmp_items";s:1:"0";s:23:"shopping_cart_act_items";s:1:"1";s:12:"_uslk_visits";s:1:"1";s:14:"_uslk_referrer";s:29:"http://dev-sti.planetart.com/";s:18:"_uslk_bootstrapped";s:1:"1";s:8:"_uslk_ct";s:1:"0";s:8:"_uslk_co";s:1:"0";s:12:"_uslk_active";s:1:"0";s:22:"_uslk_page_impressions";s:2:"45";s:15:"_uslk_app_state";s:6:"Idle;0";},User ID: 817239, User Name: Semirindi, User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36, \nUser  IP address: 127.0.0.1, \nUser session ID: pvbmhif06sd25584sl75tl7qs3,CART ID:64a0d1346aff6ff6aeb7f6a78c9ad156
```

So when I do `var_dump($_POST['loginfo'])`, I only get half of the string instead of all. This is the output of the `var_dump($_POST['info'])`  .. any idea why ?

```
string 'Cookie Info: a:20:{s:11:"NO_TRACKING";s:4:"true";s:9:"PHPSESSID";s:26:"pvbmhif06sd25584sl75tl7qs3";s:13:"orig_referrer";s:29:"http://dev-sti.planetart.com/";s:5:"email";s:23:"semirindi@planetart.com";s:12:"cookie_check";s:4:"done";s:15:"recently_viewed";s:5:"23795";s:15:"user_last_paper";s:2:"CS";s:24:"user_last_size_RECTANGLE";s:3:"5x7";s:18:"user_last_quantity";s:2:"25";s:7:"cart_id";s:32:"64a0d1346aff6ff6aeb7f6a78c9ad156";s:23:"shopping_cart_tmp_items";s:1:"0";s:23:"shopping_cart_act_items";s:1:"1";s:12:'... (length=1057)
```

Comment: Show your input after the PHP has been interpolated

Comment: And also the result of validating the generated page: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Try this instead `value="<?= htmlspecialchars($user_log_info) ?>"`

Comment: @Phil same thing man , doesnt work

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at your `post_max_size`variable's value.
Maybe you need to adjust its value.

Have a look at this [comment on PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#101755)

Comment: And please accept the answer or otherwise let us know if that fixes it.

Comment: @BobBrown  it didn't fix it .. I changed the post_max_size to 16M and it didn't fix it . it was set to 8

Comment: @SemiM can you please open your browser's console, locate the POST request and copy&paste here the Headers?

Comment: @PauloASilva my chrome console has nothing

Comment: @SemiM You have to switch to the Network tab and then select the POST request

Comment: I realized that although it shows a truncated string , it still sends the whole data

Comment: @SemiM "it shows" are you talking about what you can access on `$_POST`? Maybe your webserver is truncating the request body because of its size. Check the link I left in the answer [link](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#101755).